# Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uri

I keep getting this error.

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

the code I have is:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(slct.Text);
if (DeleteFileOnServer(uri))
{
    nn.BalloonTipText = slct.Text + " has been deleted.";
    nn.ShowBalloonTip(30);
}
```

**Update:** the content in slct.Text is `ftp.jt-software.net/style.css`.

What gives? How is that not a valid URI format? It's plain text.

Comment: It is telling me the content of slct.Text is not a valid Uri. But it is.

Comment: @j-t-s: could you post the offending URI perhaps?

Comment: Do you get an exception when creating the Uri with new Uri or when trying to delete the file on the server?

Comment: the offending uri is: ftp.jt-software.net/style.css

Comment: @j-t-s, I assume those downvotes were coming from the people that did leave a comment and found out that you didn't update your answer. Note, you can edit your question to make it complete (and accept answers), to keep SO clean. You were missing `ftp://` or `http://` in your URI. You get my vote now ;-)

Comment: Yeah, there's a good reason it'[s missing that... Because my program automatically adds it for me :) But thank you :)

Comment: i had same issue, i was missing http:// protocol at the begin of URI

Answer (score 164):

It may help to use a different constructor for Uri.

If you have the server name

```
string server = "http://www.myserver.com";
```

and have a relative Uri path to append to it, e.g.

```
string relativePath = "sites/files/images/picture.png"
```

When creating a Uri from these two I get the "format could not be determined" exception unless I use the constructor with the UriKind argument, i.e.

```
// this works, because the protocol is included in the string
Uri serverUri = new Uri(server);

// needs UriKind arg, or UriFormatException is thrown
Uri relativeUri = new Uri(relativePath, UriKind.Relative); 

// Uri(Uri, Uri) is the preferred constructor in this case
Uri fullUri = new Uri(serverUri, relativeUri);
```

Answer (score 66):

Check possible reasons here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=VS.100).aspx

EDIT:

You need to put the protocol prefix in front the address, i.e. in your case "ftp://"

Comment: Nothing wrong at all. I was doing everything really quickly, and I accidently clicked the down button, and it said that unless the question is edited i cannot undo it, so if you could kindly edit your question or something, i can re-upvote you :) So sorry about that :-( I didn't mean to downvote you

Comment: voting up back instead of j-t-s. Since the latter disappeared :)

Comment: @Simon, I just voted you UP again, sorry about the HUGE delay! You can punch me 2times lol

Comment: @Simon, I have the same problem, but my protocol prefix is followed by the port number (8080) in the address bar of the browser, i.e. the complete URI would be: "Http://localhost/8080/api/nameOfMyRestController". How can I manage this?

Answer (score 21):

Better use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(string uriString, UriKind uriKind)`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx

Example :-

```
 if(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(slct.Text,UriKind.Absolute))
 {
        Uri uri = new Uri(slct.Text);
        if (DeleteFileOnServer(uri))
        {
          nn.BalloonTipText = slct.Text + " has been deleted.";
          nn.ShowBalloonTip(30);
        }
 }
```

Comment: This does not provide a solution. It just checks if the URI is correct and if so, it continues.

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like it might be a realative uri. I ran into this problem when doing cross-browser Silverlight; on my [blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/02/cross-browser-silverlight.html) I mentioned a workaround: pass a "context" uri as the first parameter.

If the uri is realtive, the context uri is used to create a full uri. If the uri is absolute, then the context uri is ignored.

**EDIT:** You need a "scheme" in the uri, e.g., "ftp://" or "http://"

Answer (score 12):

I worked around this by using [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(slct.Text);

if (DeleteFileOnServer(builder.Uri))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue for me was that when i got some domain name, i had:

cloudsearch-..-..-xxx.aws.cloudsearch... **[WRONG]**

http://cloudsearch-..-..-xxx.aws.cloudsearch... **[RIGHT]**

hope this does the job for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a debugging error like this while trying to set up Docker.

I've set the docker setting in "launchSettings.json" as follows.

Problem has solved.

```
"Docker":
{
    "commandName": "Docker",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/",
    "publishAllPorts": false,
    "useSSL": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the xml comment file exists or not if you enable SwaggerDoc for the app.