# Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: asp.net, uri

In a web application that I have set up in IIS 7 I am receiving the error in the title when navigating to this URL:

```
http://localhost/EnglewoodCO/Default.aspx
```

However, when I go to this URL there is no problem and the page correctly loads:

```
http://localhost/EnglewoodCO/Default.aspx?App=Admin
```

Could someone please give me some ideas of what to even check?

The only thing that comes to mind is that perhaps a path is set incorrectly in a .config file somewhere. I don't know what else to check and I was just hoping someone might have another suggestion.

Comment: What exact error are you receiving?

Comment: The one in the title. Here is the exception copied and pasted: Exception Details: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a Stack Trace would be greatly helpful to identify the problem.

If you are using [Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a) you might wanna check the following question:
[Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887924/invalid-uri-the-format-of-the-uri-could-not-be-determined)