# C# Problem with Uri for non-ASCII File Names

Tags: c#, string, exception, unicode, uri

I want to access this file:

```
    var myUri = new Uri("سلام.txt");
```

I need Uri format for some reason and I can't use string.
Exception is:

```
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887924/invalid-uri-the-format-of-the-uri-could-not-be-determined) did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify `UriKind.Relative` if you don't provide full Uri string.

```
var uri = new Uri("سلام.txt", UriKind.Relative);
// or provide full Uri
var uri = new Uri("http://foo.bar/سلام.txt");
```